# How to determine transport type in sockio?

Tags: socket.io

in socketIO , how to check the transport type (i.e. xhr-polling or websockets or flash sockets) on which client & server communicating ? (i'm using netty server with java)
thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

On the client side, you can use the variable `socket.socket.transport.name`. Server-side you can use the variable `socket.transport` or you can check the name of the transport by connection ID.

Answer (score 1):

In your connection callback, the expression is `io.transports[conn.id].name`.  As a simple test:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(conn) {
    console.log(io.transports[conn.id].name);
});
```