# How do I determine transport type in socket.io consistently (version >= 1.3)

Tags: socket.io, socket.io-1.0

This question has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041387/how-to-determine-transport-type-in-sockio), but that answer is no longer correct. I'd like to determine transport type at runtime - if I have a ws connection, I'll route my REST requests over the websocket, and if I'm on polling, I'll do the old-fashioned http requests.

I can test `io().socket.io.engine.transport.constructor.name` in the client, which works (I get either WS or XHR as those are the constructor names), but that feels awfully brittle. It'd be rad if there were a standard way to do this.

Comment: socket.io.engine.transport.name is a bit shorter. You can also test if transport.ws is not null : if(socket.io.engine.transport.ws) wsfunc(...) else xhrfunc(...). I don't fully understand why you need this information in the client, as far as socket.io handles websocket and xhr connections in the same way.

Comment: Hmm, `if (transport.ws)` seems a lot better than relying on the class name being used for the transport (the latter being maybe subject to change in a later version).  As to the use case, normally I'd load `/api/items/1`, `/api/others/1` and so forth over a https connection in another part of the webapp. Wiring these requests into the websocket means no TLS handshake overhead on each request (bascially a janky SPDY optimization). If the WS isn't present, it's more efficient to use normal http requests for api endpoint stuff and leave socket.io stuff for server-push realtime stuff.